Variable Error in Gazebo
I am trying to build this repo from GitHub: gazebo_domain_randomization
and I get an error:
Gazebo error: Thesis_ws/src/gazebo_domain_randomization/gazebo_physics_plugin/src/     gazebo_physics_plugin.cpp:250:25: error: variable 'gazebo::common:Color ambient' has initializer but incomplete type

From what I understood that they are trying to create a variable of type Color and the Gazebo installed from Ubuntu binaries does not have a file Color.h.
But I found this one gazebo repo on GitHub which has color.h.
The repo is here: https://github.com/arpg/Gazebo/tree/master
My question is, is my intuition correct, or are there any other reasons for the error?
Also, if my intuition is correct, will the process of installation of the gazebo GitHub repo be same as what is mentioned on gazebo website (Installing gazebo from source).
Can anyone please help me?
